# Ant-design overrides all custom classes in Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, antd

I want to use ant-design to create a dashboard in next-js, however, antd generates these types of classes which always take priority:
[image]

I would like to be able to write my styles in tailwindCSS directly in the className property of the components (for example to change the color), but this does not work. Therefore, I added the classes to a local module, but they still get lower priority than the ant-design classes.

The only way to override the ant-design classes is by adding the classes to the globals.css file included in _app.tsx. However, not only is this very inconvenient, but I also don't want to load all these classes on every single page just to override simple component.

Here is my code, if anybody could let me know if there is any way to custom style the components that would be fantastic:

```
import {
    MenuFoldOutlined,
    MenuUnfoldOutlined,
    UploadOutlined,
    UserOutlined,
    VideoCameraOutlined,
} from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd';
import styles from './Dashboard.module.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;

export default function Home() {
    const [collapsed, setCollapsed] = useState(false);
    return (
        <Layout className={styles.layout}>
            <Sider className={styles.logo} trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={collapsed}>
                <div className={styles.trigger} />
                <Menu
                    theme="dark"
                    mode="inline"
                    defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
                    items={[
                        {
                            key: '1',
                            icon: <UserOutlined />,
                            label: 'nav 1',
                        },
                        {
                            key: '2',
                            icon: <VideoCameraOutlined />,
                            label: 'nav 2',
                        },
                        {
                            key: '3',
                            icon: <UploadOutlined />,
                            label: 'nav 3',
                        },
                    ]}
                />
            </Sider>
            <Layout className={styles.siteLayout}>
                <Header
                    className={styles.siteLayoutBackground}
                    style={{
                        padding: 0,
                    }}
                >
                    {React.createElement(collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined, {
                        className: 'trigger',
                        onClick: () => setCollapsed(!collapsed),
                    })}
                </Header>
                <Content
                    className="site-layout-background"
                    style={{
                        margin: '24px 16px',
                        padding: 24,
                    }}
                >
                    Content
                </Content>
            </Layout>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

And the Dashboard.module.css:

```
.layout {
    @apply min-h-screen
}

.logo {
    @apply h-8 w-8 m-4 bg-white/30
}

.trigger {
    @apply px-6 bg-transparent text-xl leading-4 p-0 cursor-pointer transition-all duration-300
}

.trigger:hover {
    @apply text-[#1890ff]
}

.site-layout .site-layout-background {
    @apply bg-white
}
```